# Remove the clone of a element being dragged, when the element is dropped

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

In my code below, sometimes when I drag a list item to a new position in the list then release, the clone of the element that is made by the drag, glides back to it's original position before going to where I dragged to. There is a GIF [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgmVv.gif) that shows the issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function getNextElement(y) {
    var next = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")].map(element => {
        var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            element: element,
            top: rect.top
        }
    }).reduce((a, b) => Math.abs(b.top - y) < Math.abs(a.top - y) ? b : a).element;
    next == null ? next = ul.firstElementChild : next;
    return next;
}

document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.draggable = true;

    draggable.ondragstart = event => ul.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    draggable.ondrag = event => draggable.classList.add("dragging");

    draggable.ondragend = event => {
        draggable.classList.remove("dragging")
        ul.removeChild(ul.lastElementChild)
    };

    draggable.ondragover = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var next = getNextElement(event.clientY);
        var dragging = document.querySelector('.dragging');
        if (dragging !== null) {
            if (next === null) {
                try {
                    ul.appendChild(dragging);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(dragging);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    ul.insertBefore(dragging, next);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(dragging)
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400&display=swap');

#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    width: 200px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Inter";
    padding-left: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

li {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-radius: 9px;
}

.dragging {
    color: transparent;
    border: 2px dashed #ddd;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not seeing the issue shown in the gif in SO snippet. Does the issue still persist in SO snippet for u?

Comment: @aleng - Yep, the issue is there for me. And just to clarify the list technically does work, although sometimes the dragged element is gliding back to where is was before jumping to where it's been dragged to.